# Turning off country borders via the KML

Tags: kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Google Earth defaults to the "Borders and Labels" (i.e, showing country outlines) on.  I have KMZ/KML files where I want the borders turned off.  I've searched documents describing the KML and can't find anything related to layers.

I also tried saving KMZ files with and without the borders turned on, and they are identical.

Anyone know how to access the layers through the KML API?

Answer (score 0):

You can't yet turn on/off layers in Google Earth directly via KML. Currently it's a manual action done by user of Google Earth.

However, there is currently a directive to turn on/off historical imagery, streetview, and sun light modes.
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxvieweroptions

But you can turn the layers on/off easily via the GE API:

To enable a specific layer:

```
  ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_NAME, true)
```

To disable a layer:

```
  ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_NAME, false);
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/layers#layers

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't have constants defined for the individual layers within ge.LAYER_BORDERS  but if you look in the KML file, each "Folder" node has an ID, so, as JasonM1 says, you can use enableLayerById for each one you want to switch off, having switched on the top containing node (ge.LAYER_BORDERS in this case).

Here's the code i used to clean up the "Borders and Labels" layer via the API:

```
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById("530286de-c7b3-11dc-938c-dd553d8c9902", false);       // internation borders
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById("cfdff130-394a-11e0-98fa-dd5743f1dfd8", false);       // coastline
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById("533444c6-c7b3-11dc-b02e-dd553d8c9902", false);       // 1st level borders too
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById("534ab67a-c7b3-11dc-a2a7-dd553d8c9902", false);       // 2nd level borders too
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById("e2334aaa-e853-11df-9192-77880e18aa7d", false);       // geographic features
```

*p.s. I can't seem to find where i got the "borders and labels.kml" file now, but it was probably here somewhere, will continue looking...*