# Hiding a country label

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Is it possible to 'overlay' a country in Google Earth Plugin in such a way that the labels shown by the 'LAYER-BORDERS' layer are not visible ?

Or would it be possible to 'override' certain labels within the 'LAYER-BORDERS' layer ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this question: [Turning off country borders via the KML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503057/turning-off-country-borders-via-the-kml), just use different ID's in the enableLayerById calls for the different "sub-layers".