# Google Earth API: Turn off labels

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin

In the following post it is mentioned that you can turn off "individual layers within ge.LAYER_BORDERS" by looking "in the KML file" and getting the layer ID. Anyone know what KML file to look in to find this ID? The reason I ask, is because I would like to turnoff the state/country labels.

[Turning off country borders via the KML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503057/turning-off-country-borders-via-the-kml/18979306#18979306)

Thanks,
Brandon

Answer (score 0):

The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/layers#layers) states that "Not all of the layers that are available in the Google Earth desktop client are available with the plugin."

Available layers in Google Earth API are:

- LAYER_BORDERS
- LAYER_BUILDINGS
- LAYER_BUILDINGS_LOW_RESOLUTION
- LAYER_ROADS
- LAYER_TERRAIN
- LAYER_TREES

The *LAYER_BORDERS* layer shows country and area borders, and place labels for cities, states, countries, oceans, etc. so disabling this layer would remove state/country labels.